# Are there local websites for booking hotels in Caracas/Venezuela?

Tags: hotels, venezuela

I'm planning a trip to Caracas and looking at Booking.com, the selection of hotels seems pretty poor with only 22 options. Kayak has 38 options which is better but still seems like there should be more hotels in a city of 3 million people.

Are there any local Venezuelan websites for booking hotels which have more options? I've tried searching for other websites in Google but unfortunately couldn't find anything significantly better than Kayak.

Answer (score 6):

as a Venezuelan, i can tell is really hard to find something, we are not so good organized and tourism is lacking since criminality and economics have almost ruined the spot for tourist...

but you can still try sites like:

https://www.venezuelatuya.com/hoteles/caracas.htm